Why is ForEach/List working only for some Arrays?
I have a SwiftData Model and recently added a new Array which is holding "Sections" as Strings. No matter what I try I can't make Swift to go trough this Array in any way using ForEach, For or a List. I always get this error:
Generic parameter 'V' could not be inferred

If I use another Array tapas.asanas it works flawlessly.
Here is the Code Snippet, the error is shown at the Section("Sections") Line.
Section("Sections") {
    TextField("Add a new Section", text: $sectionName)
        .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
    Button(action: {
        tapas.tapasSections.append(sectionName)
        sectionName = ""
    }, label: {
        Text("Add Section")
    })
    
    List(tapas.tapasSections) { name in
        Text("\(name)")
    }
}

And here is the SwiftData Model:
import Foundation
import SwiftData


@Model
class Tapas {
    var name: String
    
    /// Time Frame of the Tapas
    var currentDay: Int
    var lengthInDays: Int = 21
    var lastDay: Date
    var startDay: Date = Date()
    
    var intention: String
    var intentionEvoked: Bool = false
    var rules: String = ""
    var supportTime: [Date] = []
    var tapasSections: [String] = []
    
    var recuperated: Bool
    var tapasType: String
    var isActive: String
    
    var recupType: String                   /// NoRecoup, TimedRecoup, UnlimitedRecoup for No recouperations, Recouperations before Last Day, And even after
    var resetTime: Date
    
    var color: String
    
    /// Adding a relation to TapasAsana, as one Tapas has many Asanas
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var asanas = [TapasAsana]()
    
    
    init(name: String = "", intention: String = "", currentDay: Int = 1, lengthInDays: Int = 49, lastDay: Date = .now, recuperated: Bool = false, tapasType: String = "hatha", isActive: String = "dormant", recupType: String = "NoRecoup", resetTime: Date = .now, color: String = "blue") {
        self.name = name
        self.intention = intention
        self.currentDay = currentDay
        self.lengthInDays = lengthInDays
        self.lastDay = lastDay
        self.recuperated = recuperated
        self.tapasType = tapasType
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.recupType = recupType
        self.resetTime = resetTime
        self.color = color
    }
}

As I said before, this relationship Array called asanas is working in any ForEach or List, also in this code above. Replacing tapas.tapasSections with tapas.asanas resolves the error.

Why do you have a List inside a Section?

It was just my last attempt, before I had ForEach. But also in another Place I have actually a List inside a Section to have it ordered and with the section title.

The reason this is not compiling is the fact that String is not Identifiable but the initializer for the List you are using needs it to be.
There are 2 possible solutions here:

Make String conform to Identifiable
  extension String: Identifiable{
      public var id: Self{ self }
  }


Use a different initializer for List
  List(tapas.tapasSections, id: \.self) { name in
      Text("\(name)")
  }



Replacing tapas.tapasSections with tapas.asanas works because the @Model wrapper makes the TapasAsana class conform to PersistentModel which makes it conform to Identifiable.
Documentation
